# Appending paramaters to each m3u8 and ts file while playing live stream

Tags: nginx, video.js, live-streaming

I am using videojs in live streaming environment and using nginx secure URLs to protect the stream. See here for the details - https://www.nginx.com/blog/securing-urls-secure-link-module-nginx-plus/

The algorithm works fine and the player is able to detect when the live.m3u8 file becomes available. However, when playing the stream, I just get a spinning wheel. On the JS console, I see that the sub-playlist e.g. live_109.m3u8 URL does not have the required md5 hash and expiry timestamp and hence nginx is returning 403.

The stream URL format is -

```
https://example.com/video/live.m3u8?md5=xznbbmbbbbbxncb&expire=123456788
```

When I play the stream, the console suggest that the player is now trying to call

```
https://example.com/video/live_109.m3u8
```

And since without the md5 and expiry parameters, nginx will send 403, I am getting that.

Adding `?md5=xznbbmbbbbbxncb&expire=123456788` works perfect with the live_109.m3u8 also.

I am sure the same problem will be with the individual segments (.ts files)

My question here is that how can I append `?md5=xznbbmbbbbbxncb&expire=123456788` to every .m3u8 and .ts file being called from the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The following snippet shows as to how to do it with the help of [http-streaming library](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming) of videojs -

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@videojs/http-streaming@1.11.2/dist/videojs-http-streaming.js"></script>

<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" 
  data-setup='{}'>
  </video>

  <script>
    videojs.Hls.xhr.beforeRequest = function(options){
      options.uri = options.uri+'/liveout/?md5=_PwgAm2z_kO8FgmWRWXvhQ&expires=1574698730';
      //.replace('cloudfront.net', 'foo.com');
      console.log(options);
      return options;
    };
    var player=videojs('my_video_1');
    player.ready(function() {
      this.src({
        src: 'https://d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/bipbop-advanced/bipbop_16x9_variant.m3u8',
        type: 'application/x-mpegURL'
      });

    });    
  </script>
```