# Query parameters for m3u8 and ts urls. Hls.js

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8, hls.js

**Question:**

I'm struggling with adding query params to urls. I want to add `?md5=<string>&expires=<number>` for each request url (m3u8, ts). I heard [`fetchSetup`](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#fetchsetup) would be useful but I didn't see any examples, does anyone know how to solve this problem?

I already tried this but nothing happened:

```
const hlsConfig = {
  fetchSetup: (context, initParams) => {
    initParams.credentials = 'include';
    return new Request(
      context.url + '?md5=test123&expires=test123', 
      initParams
    );
  }
}
```

**Related issues on Github:** [#2152](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/2152), [#2142](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/2142).

Same question with `video.js`: [Appending paramaters to each m3u8 and ts file while playing live stream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59106629/9464680)

Answer (score 2):

We've solved it by modifying window.XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open to update url. May be something related to xhrSetup (which was given a try but didn't spend much time).